# springmvc with rest - delegating request to different versions of rest controllers

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am designing a REST controller layer with the concept of different versioning which might happen in the future.

I am thinking of having separate classes with version number as follows.

```
@RequestMapping("/v1/api")
@RestController
class V1RestController {

}


@RequestMapping("/v2/api")
@RestController
class V2RestController {

}
```

Or V2RestController might extend V1RestController depending on the requirements. This is just a draft idea. But my question is if there is any Spring MVC api which can catch the URL and look up the version '/v1/api or /v2/api' and delegate the request to the right controller.

Based on my research, the best way is to make it backward-compatible, but i am sure that the reality is different and there would be some cases to have different implementations.

I know that there are other ways to design the rest controller layer for different versioning, but for now, i would like to take this approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you implement it this way, then there is no need to intercept the URL. Spring already knows which controller to use when the `@RequestMapping` is specified

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is if there is any Spring MVC api which can catch the URL and look up the version '/v1/api or /v2/api' and delegate the request to the right controller.

DispatcherServlet intercepts the request (what to intercept it looks in "web.xml" ), and then DispatcherServlet looks at the request URL and looks for the controller whose "value" parameter (the "@RequestMapping" annotation) matches the request URL, if a match is found: control is transferred in the corresponding controller. Something like this.